# Integrating rasa bot with twilio voice

Tags: twilio, rasa

I am trying to build a telephony voicebot using Rasa,I’m just getting started with Rasa, and wondering whether it is possible to integrate rasa bot with twilio voice ,sms is working fine on Programmable SMS .Can anyone please help me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

We have used 2 different ways to achieve this. As this is for my company, I do not have the right to publish any source code, but this should help you find the way:

1-via Twilio studio, you can just use a block to call a Twilio function and there use "got" npm module (to be addded in Twilio function management tab) to launch a rest API call to you RASA NLU server (or RASA core if you need more than just NLU) and get back the intent(+other info if you want).
2-if you have the possibility to host a backend server (a "middelman"), then you can follow the tutorial at Twilio and expose 4 routes for call controle. In your backend, you will recuperate the utterance(speech) of the gather() function and you can make an API call to your RASA server with it as argument. The backend should contain the logic to react on the intent detected by RASA.

Example (for both solutions) : detected intent is "talk to a manager", then the Twilio command should be a transfer of the call to number xxx. If the detected intent is "talk to accounting department", then you should transfer to number yyy. (jut an example but you see the point). 
Twilio has a good tutorial to start with (and a github repo you can clone) .
You can start by having a look at https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-respond-to-incoming-phone-calls-node-js (sorry I link everyting to nodeJS without knowing what you use, but some other languages are also available).

For me solution 1 is faster and allowed us to start quickly. 
Solution 2 is more professional because :
-it gives you more controle (possibility to integrate with DB server, action server, CRM, ...)
-make security people happy by hosting business data inside your own infra (instead of Twilio studio and/or Twilio function.
For info : Twilio has a SOC compliance report - a banking-level security program / if you really need to (and you are ready to pay for it)
-it makes you free and you can replace Twilio, RASA or both when you want.

Nb : Twilio does not really help you a lot in the tutorials as they have their own fully integrated solution (Twilio Autopilot) to integrate NLU and voice call.